# Facepunch Steamworks initialization failed, Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, steam, steamworks-api

I want to make a multiplayer game and use facepunch steamworks to create a lobby. I am trying to initialize and validate the client.

```
try
{
    Steamworks.SteamClient.Init(480);
    Debug.Log(Steamworks.SteamClient.IsValid);

}
    catch ( System.Exception e )
{
    Debug.Log(e.Message);
}
```

But after running this code I get a System.NullReferenceException error. Maybe I installed the library incorrectly. Has anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try installing it this way

1. Download the latest release on GitHub.
2. Open the folder and open the unity folder. You should see something like this:[image]
3. Copy all this into a folder called "Plugins" in unity. if it does not exist create it [image]